# "Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerIDTable. No matching constructor was found" exceptions on Alarm clock event

Tags: events, list-manager

My UAT logs are filled with the below logs. Could you please direct which area I should start looking to debug this issue.

```
WARN  Could not find constructor in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerIDTable. The constructor parameters may not match or it may be an abstract class. Parameter info: Count: 1. Parameter types: System.String
Heartbeat 04:42:27 

ERROR Exception in alarm clock event subscriber.
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException
Message: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerIDTable. No matching constructor was found.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Data.IDTables.IDTable.GetKeys(String prefix)
   at Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.Pipelines.Locking.GetLockedLists.GetLockedLists.Process(GetLockedListsArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.PipelineBasedContactListStore`2.GetLockedListIds()
   at Sitecore.ListManagement.ListManager`2.GetLockedLists()
   at Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Services.AlarmClock.Heartbeat_Beat(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your UAT is a Content Delivery Server and the List Manager is not disabled on it.

Taken from the official [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server) (this one is for 8.2, but it hasn`t changed much from previous versions)

```
Note
You must completely disable List Manager and Path Analyzer on a content delivery server.
```

So you will fix the error by removing the `/App_Config/Include/ListManagement`
folder from the CD server.

Also it worth taking a look at the config enable/disable excel spreadsheet that Sitecore Provides for each Sitecore Version.

Comment: Also see: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/360/automating-server-role-configuration

Comment: To add a little detail to @MarkCassidy comment,  Sitecore produces a Config Enable/Disable Config that explains in detail which configs need to be enabled for various roles. It contains a small amount of bugs. For example, it says the ScaledCM.config file should be enabled for CD, but it's really meant for CM.